# Como puedo enviar o capturar un arreglo obtenido por ajax en laravel 8, y utilizarlo en el section html y no en el success de la función

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, ajax

Lo que recibo de La respuesta del ajax lo trabajo en la misma función, pero me gustaría enviarlo al html para mayor comodidad y mejor trabajo con las variables, lo que recibo es una consulta sql le envío 3 variables y me devuelve los Datos de la reserva x pero trabajo todo en La misma función javascript como concatenado todo

Comment: Hola, Bienvenido@. Las publicaciones que no contienen una descripción (codigo) de un problema y donde se ubica este en especifico, no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Por favor, revisa [como hacer un pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y edita tu pregunta para que podamos ayudarte. Gracias

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

como estás? . Por favor para generar una mejor respuesta, es necesario que por lo menos publiques algo del codigo utilizado para tener una base de lo que estas intentando hacer.

Si ya obtienes los datos que envías desde Ajax al controlador de Laravel, para retornarlos a la vista puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera.

```
public function response(Request $request)
{
    if(isset($request->arrayAjax)){
    $arrayAjax = $request->arrayAjax;
        return view('home', ['valores' => $arrayAjax]);
    }
}
```

Después desde tu vista Blade para imprimir los valores pasados desde el controlador.

```
@foreach ($valores as $valor)
    {{ $valor }}
@endforeach
```

Saludos!